# Android Expandable List View custom child view onSizeChanged always get zero

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, android-view

The ExpandableListView's `getChildView` is inflated initially from a list of texts read from arraylist. If an item is selected (single choice mode), then i would like to change the child view to a custom view, say an image.

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView != null) {
            Log.e("EffectsAdapter", "convertView != null");
            if (getClicked(groupPosition, childPosition)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getClicked true");
                CustomView cv= new CustomView (mInflator.getContext());
                cv.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        //      ProgressBar pgbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                return cv;//convertView;

            }
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.lv_child, null);

        }
```

If i use the CustomView in **xml**,wrapped inside a LinearLayout, then the height and   weight are as per the `WRAP_CONTENT`

**But** The `onSizeChanged` of the view always receives height as zero if instantiated like above code, why??

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwid, int oldhght) {
        Log.e(TAG,"onsizeChanged w = "+String.valueOf(width)+" h= "+String.valueOf(height)
                +"oldw = "+String.valueOf(oldwid)+" oldh = "+String.valueOf(oldhght));
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        // initialize();
    }
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason :) Curious about !

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I fixed it by changing view's layout_height from wrap_content to match_parent in layout's xml

Comment: It is trivial when it is match_parent